# How to fix the not loading Images and CSS in my project?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I setup the JavaScript development environment using the following way.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Seth-on-the-Road/Codemash-2017/Build-a-JavaScript-Development-Environment-in-30-minutes

My HTML looks like. (It's simple)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background-image: url("weather.png");
                background-repeat: repeat;
            }
        </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hi All</h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

Image and CSS both are in the same folder. But, neither inline CSS nor external CSS working. 
If I put this in the simple HTML file it's working but, after javascript dev env it; not working.

Following are my dependencies in package.json.

```
"author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "eslint": "^5.12.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 6,
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "jest": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "no-console": "off",
      "no-debugger": "warn"
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "latest"
    ]
  }
```

I got error like:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/index.css"

Following is my server file.

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import open from 'open';

const port = 3000;
const app = express();

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../src/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        open('http://localhost:' + port);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm so confused because of your `Webpack` using without using `react`. But anyway, I know about Images. you should declare a loader for image file like below:

```
{
    test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules[\\\/])/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        limit: 1024,
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        publicPath: 'img/',
        outputPath: 'img/'
    }
}
```

But for your CSS, it is where I became confused, in react I should import the CSS engine in root component and the webpack generate a CSS file for me, but in your project, really I don't know. maybe it should be written like below:

```
import CSS from 'styles.css'; // or any file like styles.scss or styles.less
```

Then Use `ExtractTextPlugin` for generating CSS file:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules[\\\/])/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'css-loader'
            }
        ]
    })
}
```

If you wanna set `css-loader` option use below:

```
{
    test: /\.pcss$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules[\\\/])/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    modules: true,
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    localIdentName: '[local]', // for production it should be [hash:base64:5]
                    sourceMap: true,
                }
            }
        ]
    })
},
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion i removed webpack and still it's not working

Comment: If i am not using webpack i need to use any loader?

Comment: @ketan No, `webpack` is great module bundler and task manager. revert it, please. I was confused because I don't know it can be in any project that doesn't have reactjs. set the configuration that I wrote.